# Calculating percentage of a profit

Tags: percentages

399 is the amount you will gain if you invest 345

Therefore profit is 399 - 345 = 54

I want to express profit as percentage of the amount that you'll get back but I'm not sure why 2 methods give different results and what's the meaning of another one.

Method 1:

399 / 345 = ~1.15 meaning profit is 15%

Method 2:

345 / 399 = ~0.86 meaning profit is 1 - 0.86 = 14%

Which of the 2 methods is correct to express profit as percentage and what does the other method mean?

For instance I want to be able to avoid investment unless I'll profit 20% on top of invested amount.

Comment: It would make more sense to set the profit in relation to the invested sum , here $\frac{54}{345}\cdot 100$ %

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, but what's the meaning of the result of 2nd method? I suppose 1-0.86 makes no sense and 0.86 is the cost of investment?

Comment: Method $1$ is basically the same as my method since $1$ is subtracted. Method $2$ gives $99$ % for $1/100$ although we multiply our money by factor $100$. This is not plausible and must mean something completely different.

Comment: Yeah the result of 345/399 (2nd method) is percentage of 345 within 399, but other than this I don't know the meaning, but at least we can be sure it's not profit! thank you!